# How to convert Session Variable to Integer Type in C#

Tags: c#

I am using C#

I am trying to check whether my  login attempt is not more than 3, I mean with the below condition:

```
if (((int)Session["LoginAttempt"]) != 3)
{
}
```

In Login failed condition I am doing increment like below:

```
Session["LoginAttempt"] = ((int) Session["LoginAttempt"]) + 1;
```

But it is giving me this error: **"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."**

Suggestions please!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Sorry Guys,

I just changed the integer converting code from

```
((int) Session["LoginAttempt"])
```

to

```
Convert.ToInt32(Session["LoginAttempt"]) + 1;
```

and now it is working fine for me, please suggest incase of any issues in it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Try the magic code:

```
Session["LoginAttempt"] = ((int?)Session["LoginAttempt"] ?? 0) + 1;
```

This will convert the session variable `Session["LoginAttempt"]` to a nullable `int` (an `int` that can be `null`) the `?? 0` provides a value 0 if it is null, so the calculation succeeds.

The `Session["LoginAttempt"]` can be null if it is not initialized before.

Answer (score 5):

You need to test to see if the `Session` variable exists before you can use it and assign to it.

Here you are doing an increment:

`Session["LoginAttempt"] = ((int) Session["LoginAttempt"]) + 1;`

But, if the `Session["LoginAttempt"]` does not exist, this will explain your error.  A quick `null` test before the increment should sort it out.

```
if (Session["LoginAttempt"] != null)
    Session["LoginAttempt"] = ((int)Session["LoginAttempt"]) + 1;
```

Answer (score 4):

Why not encapsulate the LoginAttempt value as a property and auto-assign a value:

```
protected int LoginAttempt
{
    get
    {
        if (Session["LoginAttempt"] == null)
        {
            Session["LoginAttempt"] = 1;
        }
        return Convert.ToInt32(Session["LoginAttempt"].ToString());
    }
    set
    {
        Session["LoginAttempt"] = value;
    }
}
```

so that the main body of the function is more readable:

```
if (LoginAttempt < 3)
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It will do that the first time you try to set it if you haven't previously initialised it. Try this instead:

```
if (Session["LoginAttempt"] == null)
    Session["LoginAttempt"] = 1;
else
    ((int)Session["LoginAttempt"]) += 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Divide your nontrivial code in parts:

```
int sessionLogicAttempt = (int)Session["LoginAttempt"];
int someValue = sessionLogicAttempt + 1;
Session["LoginAttempt"] = someValue;
```

Also, add assertions to check for the values you are assuming.

Answer (score 0):

```
//read
object attemptObj = Session["LoginAttempt"]
int attempt = 0;
if (attemptObj != null) attempt = (int)attemptObj ;

////write
Session["LoginAttempt"] = attempt++;
```

Answer (score 0):

try make sure not to cast something that is possibly a null value.

```
int i = Session["val"] == null ? 0 : (int)Session["val"];
```

though this could mess you up as well if some other programmer uses your "val" session and put a non int value there so.

```
        int y = 0;
        if (int.TryParse(Session["val"] == null ? string.Empty : Session["val"].ToString(), out y))
        {
            // got your int value
        }
        else
        {
            // no int value in session val
        }
```